# Certain submodules of a finitely generated $R$-module are finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

> Let $R \subset S$ be commutative rings.  Let $s \in T$ where $T$ is a finitely generated $R$-module in $S$ with $R \subset T \subset S$.  I want to show that $R[s]$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module.

Let $(t_i)_{i = 1\dots n}$ be a minimal spanning set for $T$ over $R$.  Then $s^k = \sum_i s^k_{i} t_i$.  And so we have

$$
1 = \sum_i s_i^0 t_i \\
s = \sum_i s_i^1 t_i \\
\dots \\
s^n = \sum_i s_i^n t_i 
$$

Don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Do you want to show that $T$ is finitely generated or do you want to show that $R[s]$ is finitely generated? And are you talking about as modules or as rings or something else?

Comment: Edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $T$ is a ring and $t_1,\dots,t_n$ is a set of generators of $T$ as an $R$-module. Then $st_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}t_j$, $a_{ij}\in R$, $i=1,\dots,n$. Set $A=sI_n-(a_{ij})$. The previous relations can be written as follows: $A(t_1,\dots,t_n)^T=0$. (Here $^T$ denotes the transpose.) Then $(\hbox{adj}A)A(t_1,\dots,t_n)^T=0$ and since $(\hbox{adj}A)A=(\det A) I_n$ we get $(\det A)t_i=0$ for all $i$. Since $1\in T$ we can write $1$ as a linear combination of the $t_i$'s with coefficients in $R$, so $\det A=0$. This gives a monic polynomial with coefficients in $R$ that has $s$ as a root, that is, $s$ is integral over $R$. Now it's easy to prove that $R[s]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Proposition 5.1 in Atiyah-Macdonald, *Introduction to Commutative algebra*.